# Float to end with d-none

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have a button which displays up to a certain point, using `d-none d-sm-block` to achieve this. I am now finding it difficult to keep the button aligned to the end of the col when it is being displayed, in a way that was being used prior to adding d-none, something like `d-flex justify-content-md-around justify-content-lg-end`.

My question is if there is a way to align the button to the right of col while using `d-none`.

Just in case, here is the full block (with no *move button to end code*)

```
<header>
<div class="container-fluid d-grid gap-4 align-items-center p-3" style="grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 0.75fr 0.25fr;">
   <div class="d-none d-sm-block">
      <a class="btn btn-outline-light" style="width: 125px;" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register">Register</a>
   </div>
</div>
</header>
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: where's the code for the containing column/row, etc...?

Comment: My mention of col was poor, it's actually using a container, situated in header. Please see edit in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`d-block` has media query helpers `d-sm-block` etc.
`d-flex` has media query helpers `d-sm-flex` etc.

If your code is working for `d-flex` then use `d-sm-flex` *(not `d-sm-block`)*